# C++ Reverse Array of std::vector of two elements

Tags: c++

I would like to ask how can I fastly, without copying of elements reverse the array, that will always consists only from 2 std::vectors. The CGAL_Polyline is also a vector that contains points.

Currently I am doing reverse like this (works for now but I do not know if this is a correct way):

```
std::vector<CGAL_Polyline> m[2]; //array to reverse
std::vector<CGAL_Polyline> m_[2]{  m[1], m[0] };
m[0] = m_[0];
m[1] = m_[1];
```

this does not work, why?

```
std::vector<CGAL_Polyline> m[2]; //array to reverse
std::reverse(m.begin(), m.end());
```

Is there any other way to flip the order of two vectors? I do not need to reverse order of items in the vectors.

Comment: `std::swap(m[0], m[1]);`?

Comment: `m` is a C-style array, it has no methods. You can use `std::reverse(std::begin(m), std::end(m))` or `std::reverse(m, m + LENGTH_OF_M)`. Or just `std::swap`, reverse feels like an overkill

Comment: Swap worked perfectly thank you both @Kevin

Comment: and @Yksisarvinen

Comment: avoid C arrays. use `std::array<std::vector<CGAL_Polyline>, 2> m`

Comment: why to avoid C arrays?

Comment: @PetrasVestartasEPFL C arrays doesn't have value semantics and worst of all decay to pointer. Plus `std::array` is a proper standard container with all the amenities like `size()`, `begin()`, `end()` , can be used in ranged for and has the exact same performance as a C array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap):

```
std::vector<CGAL_Polyline> m[2];
...
std::swap(m[0], m[1]);
```

This will move the contents of the vectors without copying (C++11 and later. Before that it's allowed to copy).

If pre-C++11 (and if that's the case upgrade your compiler!) you can use [`std::vector::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap):

```
std::vector<CGAL_Polyline> m[2];
...
m[0].swap(m[1]);
```

Since it's guaranteed to be constant.